# Order by number of related objects

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-views, django-nonrel

I have the next models:

```
class Sentence(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)       
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()  

class Traduction(models.Model):
    sentence_from = models.ForeignKey(Sentence, related_name='st_traductions_from')
    sentence_to = models.ForeignKey(Sentence, related_name='st_traductions_to')
```

I want to get sentence objects order by the number of Traduction object related with them. I tried it with:

```
sentences = Sentence.objects.annotate(num_traductions=Count('st_traductions_from')) \
            .order_by('-num_traductions')
```

But it raise the next exception when I iterate it:

```
Caught DatabaseError while rendering: This query is not supported by the database
```

I'm using appengine and Django-nonrel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See: [App Engine Datastore Viewer, how to show count of records using GQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979358/app-engine-datastore-viewer-how-to-show-count-of-records-using-gql)

There is no count aggregate in GQL, i.e. `count(*)`. See http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html for an alternative approach.

Comment: Ok. Finally I did it adding a "num_traductions" field in Sentence model which is incremented when a new Traduction is added and related with it. I think this is a more efficient way to resolve it.