# Number of entities returned from a GQL Query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gqlquery

I'm new to Python and currently working on my first Google App Engine application.  In my program I have an 'Inbox' database model which contains string proporties like to_user, from_user, title, content, etc.  When a user logs in to my app I want to be able to count the number of messages that were sent to him/her, this way I can display it as "New Messages(x)".  I feel like I currently am using a work around because I can't find a better way.

```
user = users.get_current_user()
inbox = Inbox.gql('WHERE to_user = :to_user', to_user=user.nickname())
count = 0
for note in inbox:
    count = count+1
```

I tried using len(inbox) but that gave me an error.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421751/whats-the-best-way-to-count-results-in-gql

Answer (score 2):

In your specific case, where the number of New Messages will probably be small, I would not bother to create a counter upfront [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421751/whats-the-best-way-to-count-results-in-gql/422510#422510).
I would go with a simpler solution using [count()](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html#GqlQuery_count) function:

```
user = users.get_current_user()
inbox = Inbox.gql('WHERE to_user = :to_user', to_user=user.nickname())
count = inbox.count()
```