# Get Total number of records in gae datastore table

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

How to get the total number of records in gae datastore table ?

Query

```
    result = db.GqlQuery("Select * from stocklist ORDER BY part_number")
    print result.count()
```

The output will shows 1000 only. But it will contails more than 5000 records. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to count results in GQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421751/whats-the-best-way-to-count-results-in-gql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The count method has a default limit of 1000 which can be overridden.

ex. result.count(99999) will count up to 99,999 records.

The generally accepted best practice here is to use a [sharded counter](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html), so that you are doing the bulk of your work during the write operation rather than the read.