# Filter and sort by different fields in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The following code produces a `First ordering property must be the same as inequality filter property` error when executed because you can't order by a field at was not a filter.

```
q = Score.all()
q.filter("levelname = ", levelname)
q.filter("submitted >", int(time.time()) - (86400*7))
q.order("-score")
scoreList = q.fetch(10)
```

What I need to do is find the top 10 scores that are less than a week old.  There could be 10s of thousands (if not more) scores, so I can't just fetch them all and sort in python.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In general, every time a question of counting comes up, the consensus is that with GAE you should precompute everything you can. The way I'd approach your specific require of top 10 scores, is to create an entity that holds the top scores and update the position whenever you have a new score that outweighs the top 10.

When you compute a score, you can query for how many other scores are greater than the computed score. If the count is more than 10, you don't need to update your scores. This will be the majority of the time. If the count is equal to or greater than 10, you need to update the order, so you get your top 10 and insert the new score as appropriate.

To handle the time component, I'd have some process running that checks daily to see if a score should be evicted from the top 10, if so, grab the next highest to replace it with.

Here's a bunch of answers on a similar subject that address the design patterns and logic appropriate for GAE datastore: [What's the best way to count results in GQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421751/whats-the-best-way-to-count-results-in-gql)

Answer (score 0):

As Sologoub mentions, precomputing is the way to go.

You can many equality filters, though, so an alternative to keeping a separate list of the top scores could be to let each entity have a flag (say, a boolean value) that says whether it is eligible to be on the top scores list (in your case, no older than a week), and have a daily cron job that retrieves the list of all entities with the eligibility flag, checks the date, and changes the flag if required.

This costs more storage space (one more field per entity), but I suppose an advantage can be that you can choose dynamically how many top scores you want to return. (You can also have several of these flags, say one for all time high score and one just for the last week, etc.)